# links not working on bootstrap xs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I repeat the below div to create a grid of thumbnail wells using bootstrap 3. the problem is that the anchor links do not work on xs (neither the button or the image link), they do however work on sm, md and lg.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
  <div class="thumbnail" style="height:520px;">
    <a href="/movies/4539/burnt-offerings-1976"><img src="https://s.ynet.io/assets/images/movies/burnt_offerings_1976/medium-cover.jpg" alt="Burnt Offerings"></a>
    <div class="caption">
      <h5>Burnt Offerings</h5>
      <dl class="dl-horizontal hidden-xs">
        <dt>Year</dt><dd>1976</dd>
        <dt>Rating</dt><dd>6.5</dd>
        <dt>Runtime</dt><dd>1:56</dd>
      </dl>
      <p><a href="/movies/4539/burnt-offerings-1976" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">Download</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `ul.pager` is covering all of your elements on xs hence why nothing is clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ul.pager` is covering all of your elements on `col-xs` hence why nothing is clickable.

Here is one idea:

on your `ul.pager` add `z-index: 1;` and on your `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">` add another class you can hook onto like this `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item">` and do `.item { position: relative; z-index: 2; }`

Comment: I think this may solve a similar issue I'm having, except what is the "ul.pager" you refer to? I don't see that in OP's code. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DLev it was in OP's code on their website, not the block they shared on the question

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks! I found the answer I needed on another thread.